# nginx reverse proxy address/port already in use

Tags: nginx, web-server, reverse-proxy, port-443

I have an nginx reverse proxy, and I would like to have it forward traffic on to several sites, and listen on port 443 for all of these services.  I've seen this done several places, and seems like the normal way to have a reverse proxy setup...it listens on a single port, and forwards based on URL.

However, I have some settings that I consider to be a little weird because I have a site that uses NTLM validation through an IIS site, and because of that I am using [nginx Stream](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html)

Here's my current config files:

**/opt/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
stream {
    upstream backend {
        hash $remote_addr consistent;
        server mysite.domain.com:80 weight=5;
        server 192.168.0.5 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    }

    server {
        listen 192.168.0.2:443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /usr/local/nginx/conf/mycert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/conf/mykey.key;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

        ssl_session_timeout 5m;

        proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
        proxy_timeout 3s;
        proxy_pass backend;
    }
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }
    include /opt/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**/opt/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
server {
        listen 80 default;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

        listen 192.168.0.2:443 ssl;
        server_name myothersite.domain.com;

        ssl_certificate /usr/local/nginx/conf/mycert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/conf/mykeykey;

        ssl_session_timeout 5m;

        ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.0.6:80;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;

                proxy_redirect http:// $scheme://;

        }
}
```

When I go to restart nginx, I get the error

```
bind() to 127.0.0.1:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

I thought that under each `server` you could have it listen on the same port, but this seems to not be working.

If I remove the stream all together, and just use two other sites that don't use stream, this seems to work fine with multiple `server` sections.

Comment: You definitely can have multiple server blocks within nginx listening on the same ip/port combination. What's strange is that your error is for 127.0.0.1:443, but your listens are all on a different IP address. So I suspect your actual issue is that you have *another* application listening on 443, and then you have a default configuration (not shown here, or else you've sanitized) listening on 443.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html) - Different servers **must listen on different address:port pairs**.

Comment: Ugh, thanks, I was thinking that that line meant only for multiple streams, but it would make total sense that the stream would have that port constantly.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: That does only apply to streams, you absolutely can have multiple server blocks on the same IP/port combination (otherwise you would have no easy way to support virtual hosts). So I think your issue is different.